# c# dropdown selected index changed trigger jquery script

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I am trying to trigger jquery function when dropdown index is changed. 
Since the dropdown is making a postback I have accordion group in which one group is expanded. 
On postback I want to preserve that accordion group and leave it open. I want to trigger the jquery script and expand the same accordion group. 
On page load I have this script:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
              var accordionId = getParameterByName("policy");           
              $('#' + accordionId).collapse('show');
          });
```

It checks if there is querystring parameter 'policy' and according to that value the correct accordion is expanded.
Now since with dropdown postback I don't want to do whole response redirect since I'll lose all the data and selected dropdown values I want to trigger jquery script as well which will open the appropriate accordion.

You can see the accordion markup at this link: [twitter bootstrap accordion expand by querystring parameter in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913317/twitter-bootstrap-accordion-expand-by-querystring-parameter-in-asp-net)

Thanks in advance, Laziale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the accordion's activate event to save the current open panel to a cookie. Then after a postback, you can read the cookie value and set the open accordion panel appropriately.